# python webbrowser.opn('https://earth.google.com/web/search/')

Tags: python

I have two variables Latitude as dec1 and longitude as dec2
I want to pass these two variables in python webbrowser.open function
how to pass these two variables as dec1 coma dec2
so that I can get exact lat long in google earth
webbrowser.open('https://earth.google.com/web/search/'dec1,dec2) is not working
dec1 and dec2 must be separated with a comma

I want exactly https://earth.google.com/web/search/24.270096799999997,92.6912717999342

Comment: ```webbrowser.open('https://earth.google.com/web/search/'+dec1+','+dec2)```

Comment: Negative longitudes? Eg Michigan.

Comment: You also need a ? After the last slash and your parameter to distinguish it from a directory name.

Answer (score 0):

This should help as it applies the [string `format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to the URL:

```
lat = 24.270096799999997
lon = 92.6912717999342

webbrowser.open('https://earth.google.com/web/search/{},{}'.format(lat, lon))
```

Comment: cool can you accept the one you used? just click on the checkmark on the left to the post to make it appear green

Answer (score 0):

`webbrowser.open('https://earth.google.com/web/search/'+str(dec1)+','+str(dec2))`

convert variable to string and  append string

Answer (score 0):

You can user string concatenation, although it's not the prettiest solution:

```py
dec1 = # latitude here
dec2 = # longitude here

# If dec1 and dec2 are already strings then you don't need to convert them
webbrowser.open("https://earth.google.com/web/search/" + str(dec1) + "," + str(dec2))
```

If you are using Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings. This is probably the best solution:

```py
dec1 = # latitude here
dec2 = # longitude here
webbrowser.open(f"https://earth.google.com/web/search/{dec1},{dec2}")
```

Or if you are below Python 3.6, then you can user `format()`:

```py
dec1 = # latitude here
dec2 = # longitude here
webbrowser.open("https://earth.google.com/web/search/{0},{1}".format(dec1, dec2))
```